# TestComplete object sometimes not found

Tags: testcomplete

I have some trouble with TestComplete because sometimes it won't find my objects, sometimes it just doesn't and I get an error because the object is null.
For instance in this small function

```
function SelectCountry(country){
  var page = Sys.Browser("*").Page("*");
  var panel = page.Form("ID1");
  select = panel.FindChildByXPath("//select[@id='ID2']");
  select.ClickItem(country);
  link = page.FindChildByXPath("//a[@id='ID3']");    
  link.Click();
  page.Wait();
}
```

I get an error for 4 out of 5 runs telling me that select has not been found, but then on the one lucky run, everything passes fine.

Can anyone tell me what I have to check for?

Answer (score 1):

Try searching for your object in a loop. Use the Exists property of the object to determine if the object exists after each search of the page. Another option would be to use the Wait methods https://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/73657/
I would suggest avoiding hard coded delays for the reasons you have discovered. They way I search for page objects in my project is to do the search in a loop and log an error if not found.

```
var stopTime = Win32API.GetTickCount() + 60000;
var currentUpTime = Win32API.GetTickCount();

while (currentUpTime < stopTime) { //repeat search for element for n milliseconds
    currentUpTime = Win32API.GetTickCount();
    for (i = 0; i < attributes.length; i++) {
        var element = eval('Sys.Browser("iexplore").Page("*").' + tcMethod + '(' + '"' + attributes[i] + '"' + ',' + "'" + attributeValue + "'" + ',20000' + ')');

        if (element.Exists) {
                return element;
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a working solution. It's evident that the source of the problem is that the page is not properly loaded. So I put some hard coded stops before every stap that loades a new page.

```
aqUtils.Delay(2000);
```

Sometimes I have even to go for 5 seconds. 
This is still not very stable since for some reason delays could be higher sometimes.
Is there some way of telling TestComplete it should try to find an element during 30 seconds and only then raise an error?

Answer (score 0):

you can always put up a delay in the test with the test complete code

aqUtils.Delay(2000);

as mentioned.But this can also occur in case you are doing something very fast in the tests because of which the test reaches the point before the object is visible. That is reason why we use the delay in test to wait for object to load.

Try putting the breakpoint at the object and check for after waiting for 10 seconds.if the test passes in all the cases in this method it should be due to delay in object load.Or use the wait process mentioned in
https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/app-objects/common-tasks/waiting-process-or-window-activation.html